# Terraform template for Azure App Service, LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

This is how my terraform template looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "myAppServiceRG"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = var.servicePlanName
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = var.pricingTier
  worker_count        = var.nodesInWebFarm
}
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                = var.appName
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image     = var.dockerHubImage
      docker_image_tag = "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

and the parameters.tfvars file:

```
location        = "West Europe"
servicePlanName = "someserviceplan"
nodesInWebFarm  = 2
pricingTier     = "P1v2"
appName         = "myuniquelinuxwebapplication"
dockerHubImage  = "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp"
```

But for some reasons, when i try to do `terraform apply -var-file .\parameters.tfvars` i get this error:

> Error: creating Linux Web App: (Site Name "myuniquelinuxwebapplication" / Resource Group "myAppServiceRG"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value." Details=[{"Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"01007","Message":"The parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value.","MessageTemplate":"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.","Parameters":["LinuxFxVersion"]}}]

Does anyone knows why, and how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the Docker part from the `dockerHubImage` and it should work. So it should be something like that:

```
dockerHubImage = "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's a mismatch between your Linux service plan and your docker container.

I think changing the container to be a Linux build will fix it

The full tags are on this page (scroll down a bit) https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-samples

Comment: but `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp` is a Linux tag, isn't it?

Comment: Any other solution, as using it with the tag f.e `aspnetapp` gives the same error

Comment: hey @user346206 try setting `reserved = true` in your azurerm_service_plan resource https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/service_plan#attributes-reference

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the variable containing the Docker image was not set or set to a wrong value. Very misleading error...

Answer (score 0):

After the release of the [azurerm provider 3.63](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases/tag/v3.63.0), the `application_stack` block uses `docker_image_name` and `docker_registry_url` to refer to a docker image.

For example:

```yaml
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                    = var.appName
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id         = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      docker_image_name   = var.dockerHubImage:latest
      docker_registry_url = azurerm_container_registry.cr.login_server
    }
  }
}
```